# Windows Server 2003 DC hangs after network drivers update

Tags: networking, windows-sbs-2003, broadcom

Earlier today, we attempted to update the Broadcom BCM5716C network drivers on a Windows Server 2003. (Dell PowerEdge T310, FWIW). Since then we have not been able to boot the server in any normal mode. Safe Mode works.

Safe Mode with Networking and regular bootups hang at "Applying Network Settings." I haven't tried Last Known Good Configuration nor have I tried Directory Services Restore Mode. I should also mention that the longest I've allowed "Applying Network Settings" was perhaps 30 minutes.

I spoke to Dell since the server is under a basic warranty. They sent me the original Broadcom drivers. The trouble seems to be, however, that since I can only boot in Safe Mode, I can't install the application package as given. In safe mode, I receive the error: "The system administrator has set policies to prohibit this installation."

I can install the drivers independently, but that doesn't allow the NICs to work. The *most* I've been able to get are Code 10 errors on each NIC.

I plan to get back to the site tomorrow to attempt installation of a different NIC.

I'm wondering what else I can try.

Comment: Here's what I would try: Start the DC in safe mode. Once in safe mode launch Device Manager, then bring up the properties of the NIC and select the Driver tab, then click the Roll Back Driver button and see if it can roll back to the previous driver. If that doesn't work then I would try the Last Known Good configuration.

Comment: So many things have been tried, including the Roll Back. Sigh. I will try LKGC tomorrow.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried starting the server up without any network cables connected to the NICs?

Comment: Rex, I did, but there was something more. Please re-state your comment in the form of an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in the end was impatience on my part. I needed to wait long enough for the normal bootup to timeout during applying network settings.

When I went back to the site, I disconnected the network cables as Rex suggested above. I then turned on the server letting it boot normally. I left the office for about 40 minutes to run an errand. When I got back, the server was fully booted.

Once logged in, I need to re-setup the configuration for the NIC as it was no longer properly set up for AD. Once done, however, everything was fine.